# I get an error when I try to import files from a txt to a datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, txt

as the Problem in the title says, I am having Problems importing Data from a txt file into a datagridview. I get the error Input Array is longer than the number of columns. Here is what I am using to save my Data from the datagridview into a txt file and what I want to use to Import the data into the datagridview:

```
 private void OpenFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\gv9816\source\repos\Liste\UserData.txt");
        string[] values;


        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            values = lines[i].ToString().Split('|');
            string[] row = new string[values.Length];

            for (int j = 0; j < values.Length; j++)
            {
                row[j] = values[j].Trim();
            }
            _table.Rows.Add(row);
        }

    }

    private void SaveFile_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\gv9816\source\repos\Liste\UserData.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < _table.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < _table.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                writer.Write("\t" + DataGridViewCell.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() + "\t");
            }
            writer.WriteLine("");

        }
        writer.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Data Exported");
    }
```

Also, here is what I use to create the columns:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _table.Columns.Add("First Name", typeof(string));
        _table.Columns.Add("Last Name", typeof(string));
        _table.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));

        DataGridViewCell.DataSource = _table;
    }
```

Here is the Output in my UserData.txt file

```
Hans    |   Müller  |   12  |
```

---

[Here is what the application Looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyBRJ.png)

[And this is what is generated into the UserData file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mm4fA.png)

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Can you provide sample data? And which line do you got error?

Comment: For example if i Input a first Name , a last Name and an age and press the save button it will copy it into a txt file. I get the error in the line : _table.Rows.Add(row); of SaveFile_Click.

Comment: I wonder the data inside SampleData.txt

Comment: I edited my Question. Now you should see the Output of the txt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last `|` character is the problem, If you can't change the data inside txt file. Just change this line,

```
values = lines[i].ToString().Split('|');
```

to this,

```
values = lines[i].ToString().Split('|').Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much. Also the Problem when I try to add more than one Person, It only Shows one entry even though I put 2 in there. I can Change my Question so you know what i mean.

Comment: At SaveFile_Click_1, delete -1 from first for loop.